# Split a file on cmd

Tags: cmd.exe

Is there a way to split a file using cmd? I'm trying to split a file that's over 2 million lines into multiple files with maximum of 100000 lines.

Would it be something like this?

```
split -l 100000 *.csv
```

Can someone correct me?

Comment: here is an answer using windows PowerShell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001776/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-using-powershell#1002749

Comment: `split -l 100000 *.csv` is a Unix command. To use it you need to install Cygwin or similar.

Comment: @FrankThomas do you have a simpler answer for splitting for Windows? That sounds way too difficult to understand and implement.